# Why is it bind's argument's responsibility to unit its value?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads

The typical monad `bind` function has the following signature:

```
m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

As I understand it (and I might well be wrong,) the function `(a -> m b)` is just a mapping function from one structure `a` to another `b`. Assuming that is correct begs the question why `bind`'s signature is not simply:

```
m a -> (a -> b) -> m b
```

Given that `unit` is part of a monad's definition; why give the function `(a -> m b)` the responsibility to call `unit` on whatever value `b` it produced – wouldn't it be more sensible to make it part of `bind`?

Comment: Because for many concrete monads, there is more to the definition than just `unit`.

Comment: And actually, it's the other way round: `bind` allows you to kind of intermediately _remove_ one layer of `m`s, since it is equivalent to `flip $ \f -> join . fmap f`, where `join :: Monad m => m (m a) -> m a`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A function like `m a -> (a -> b) -> m b` would be equivalent to `fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`.  All `fmap` can do is change the values inside the action, it can't perform new actions.  With `m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b`, you can "run" the `m a`, feed that value into `(a -> m b)`, then return a new effect of `m b`.  Without this, you would only ever be able to have one effect in your program, you couldn't have two print statements sequentially, you couldn't connect to a network *and then* download a URL, and you couldn't respond to user input, you would only be able to transform the value returned from each primitive operation.  It's this operation that allows monads to be more powerful than either functors or applicatives.

Another detail here is that you aren't necessarily just wrapping a value with `unit`, that `m b` could represent an action, not just returning something.  For example, where is the call to `return` in the action `putStrLn :: String -> m ()`?  This function's signature is compatible with the second argument to `>>=`, with `a ~ String` and `b ~ ()`, but there is not call to `return` anywhere in its body.  The point of `>>=` is to sequence two actions together, not just to wrap values in a context.

Comment: Monads are not only about actions, effects and IO.

Comment: @Bergi Correct, but it is usually simple to make explanations using examples of effects and IO, particularly considering that a large number of monads are either stacked on top of IO or are tied to IO at some point.  They're more intuitive to work with.  Since the answer to OP's question is easily provided using counterexamples, only one such counterexample is needed for the reasoning to be sound.

Answer (score 6):

Because `m a -> (a -> b) -> m b` is just `fmap` which a Monas has, being functor. 
What a Monad add to a functor is the ability to `join` (or squash) a nested Monad to a simple one.
Example a list of list to simple list , or `[[1,2], [3]]` to `[1,2,3]`.

If you  replace `b` with `m b` in the `fmap` signature you end up with

```
m a -> (a -> m b) -> m (m b)
```

With a normal functor, you are stuck with your double layer of container (`m (m b)`). With a Monad,
using the `join` function, you can *squash* the `m (m b)` to `m b`. So `bind` is in fact `join.fmap`.

In fact, `join` and `fmap` can be written using only `bind` (and `return`), so in practice, it's easier to only define one function `bind`, instead of two `join` and `fmap`, even though it often simpler to write the laters.

So basically, `bind` is a mix of `fmap` and `join`.

Answer (score 4):

> As I understand it (and I might well be wrong,) the function `(a -> m b)` is just a mapping function from one structure `a` to another `b`

You're quite right about this – if you change the word "mapping" to *morphism*. For functions `a -> m b` are [morphisms](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Morphism_%28category_theory%29) of the monad's [Kleisli category](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleisli_category). In that light, the characteristic feature of monads is that you can compose Kleislis in the same way you can compose functions:

```
type Kleisli m a b = a -> m b  -- `Control.Arrow` has this as a `newtype` with `Category` instance.

-- compare (.) :: (b->c)     ->    (a->b)     ->     a->c
(<=<) :: Kleisli m b c -> Kleisli m a b -> Kleisli m a c
(f<=<g) x = f =<< g x
```

Also, you can use ordinary functions as Kleislis:

```
(return.) :: (a->b) -> Kleisli m a b
```

However, Kleislis are strictly more powerful than functions. E.g. for `m ≡ IO`, they are basically functions which can have side-effects, which as you know ordinary Haskell functions can't. So you can't turn a Kleisli back into a function – and if `>>=` accepted an `a->b` rather than a `Kleisli m a b`, but all you had was a Kleisli, there would be no way to use it.

Answer (score 2):

A function of type `a -> m b` has potentially many more capabilities than one of type `a -> b` followed by `return` (or as you call it, "unit").  In fact no "effectful" operation can be expressed in the latter form.

Answer (score 1):

Another take on this: any useful monad will have a number of operations specific to it, beyond just the ones that come from the monadic interface.  For example, the `IO` monad has `getLine :: IO String`.  Consider this very simple program:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do name <- prompt "What's your name?"
          putStrLn ("Hello " ++ name ++ "!")

prompt :: String -> IO String
prompt str = do putStrLn str
                getLine
```

Note that the type of `prompt` fits the `a -> m b` mold, but it doesn't use `return` (a.k.a. `unit`) anywhere.  This is because it uses `getLine :: IO String`, an opaque operation provided by the `IO` monad and which cannot be defined in terms of `return` and `>>=`.

Think of it this way: ultimately, `Monad` is never something you use on its own; it's an interface for plugging together things that are extrinsic to it, like `getLine` and `putStrLn`.

Comment: "extrinsic" nice! `getLine` knows how to get a line, but it doesn't know what will be done with it - `IO` lets *us* decide *that*. Someone should start collecting good monad-explanation *one-liners*, and this one should go right there. :)